# GRANT command not working in MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the below command as root user to provide accessiblity from my application.

`GRANT ALL ON communitycourts.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

But it returns `0 rows affected`, but when I dont see this in result of  `SHOW GRANTS`. Pelase help me

Comment: Do you have the `communitycourts` database? Is it spelled exactly as in your command?

Comment: Are you using root for your application? Why?

Comment: @gbn I have changed to other user now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two points to add:

1. It is recommended to use another user other than root to connect to your DB in your application. Try to use root account for administration only. This can be good only on testing machines.
2. Don't forget to `flush privileges` for the changes to take effect. This is better than restarting mysql.

Comment: As you recommended, I created a another and given grant previleges to that user. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`0 rows affected` is normal for a successful `GRANT` command.  Unsuccessful ones will display an error.

If you see `1 warning` after `0 rows affected` you should type `SHOW WARNINGS;` and check whether the warning affects you or not.  This one could:

```
Warning | 1285 | MySQL is started in --skip-name-resolve mode; you must restart it without this switch for this grant to work
```

---

The `SHOW GRANTS` command will only show the privileges that the user executing the command has.  If you are logged in as `root@localhost` or `root@192.168.0.1` then you won't see the grants for `root@%`.

Try `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either

- `communitycourts` doesn't exist
- `'root'@'%'` doesn't exist